# how to create a vertex centric index using blueprints api for Titan?

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan

I have a super node situation in my graph and I am trying to query edges of a particular vertex. I can see that titan supports vertex centric indices however, the Wiki documentation has the groovy code and I cannot find any method as `sortKey()`. I can see `signature()` method though. Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what version of Titan you are using.  The wiki docs for [Type Definitions](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Type-Definition-Overview#sortkeytitantype-and-signaturetitantype) is up to date with Titan 0.4.1.  There were extensive changes to the type system API between Titan 0.3.x and 0.4.x.

Comment: I am using titan 0.3.2

Comment: `sortKey` did not exist in 0.3.2 which is why you can't find it (though signature did).  You can read about types for that version here: http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/wikidoc/0.3.2/Type-Definition-Overview.html